# Probability of x% of Population voting Yes

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If each individual has a 50% probability of voting 'Yes' in an Merger vote (independent probabilities), what is the probability that at least 50% of individuals will vote 'Yes'?

Similarly, what is the chance that at least 20% of individuals will vote 'Yes'?

I feel like this is a very simple problem, and I am needlessly getting confused.

Comment: (1) You need to assume all individuals vote independently if you want any chance at getting answers.  (2) The answers depend on the number of voters, but an easy symmetry argument for even numbers of voters shows the answer is $1/2$. (3) For the second question, please visit our questions related to [binomial distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=self-study+binomial).

Comment: They are independently voting. I also initially thought to use binomial distribution CDF but we are not given the total number of voters, only that depending on the question x% need to be successful votes.

Comment: @Slug imagine that you have $N$ voters if that helps.

Comment: Im still a little confused. So by what you're saying, for P(50% voting yes) we estimate it as (n choose n/2)(0.5^(n/2))(0.5^(n/2))? How would we evaluate that?